# How to reference a Control in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I'm having trouble with the following code -

```
Sub ListBox7_Change()
    With Courses.ListBox7
        .AddItem "Hi"
    End With
End Sub
```

Whenever I run it, I get an error message that says "Run-time error '424': Object required".

The debugger highlights the 2nd part of the second line, "Courses.ListBox7".

I have a Sheet calles "Courses" and a ListBox on that Sheet called ListBox7. Am I referencing that ListBox incorrectly? What am I doing wrong?

I am (unfortunately) using Excel 2010.

Many thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct as long as `Courses` is `CodeName` of your sheet but I don't think so.

As long as `Courses` is simple name which you could see in Excel App then you need to change your code into this one:

```
Sub ListBox7_Change()
    With Sheets("Courses").ListBox7
        .AddItem "Hi"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kaz, I now get a Run-time error #438 : Object doesn't support this property or method. Do you know what I could have done wrong?

Comment: that will be strange but...try to close excel and run your file and code again...

Comment: Hi Kaz, that didn't work either. Thanks for trying to help, but I decided to move away from a ListBox because it was easier than trying to fix this error.